# Excel crashes during workbook.save or workbook.close

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a short piece of code that copies charts from various temporary workbooks and merges them in a separate file.

The actual manipulation process seen below runs fine, and the results file is generated as expected. **However, I run into problems after trying to close the workbook (workbook.close) or or save the results file (workbook.save) near the end, when Excel crashes.**

I have put DoEvents either side of each statement to try to give excel to catch up with itself, but to no avail!

I have also tried disabling COM addins but this doesn't seem to have helped.

Any ideas as to why this might be crashing?

Thank you so much in advance!!

```
Sub CompareResults()
Dim wkbAll As Workbook
Dim FilesToOpen
Dim x As Integer
Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
Dim wkbAllname As Variant
Dim wkbfirst As Workbook
Dim nofiles As Integer
Dim seriesname As String

'Create the new workbook
Workbooks.Add
Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook

'Select which files to merge
FilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Arbin Results Files")

If TypeName(FilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
    MsgBox "No Files were selected"
End If

'How many files?
nofiles = UBound(FilesToOpen)

'Set up the first graphs
Set wkbfirst = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FilesToOpen(1))
Set wkbfirst = ActiveWorkbook


ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ESR", "GravCap", "VolCap", "ActGravCap", "CapRet", "DisTime")).Select


Selection.Copy

wkbAll.Activate

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


'Copy each set of graphs to wkball

x = 2
While x <= UBound(FilesToOpen)
Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(filename:=FilesToOpen(x))
Set wkbTemp = ActiveWorkbook
Set wkbTemp = wkbTemp
wkbTemp.Activate

'Copy ESR Graph
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ESR").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wkbAll.Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ESR").Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
wkbTemp.Activate

'Copy GravCap Graph
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("GravCap").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wkbAll.Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("GravCap").Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
wkbTemp.Activate

'Copy ActGrav Graph
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ActGravCap").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wkbAll.Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("ActGravCap").Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
wkbTemp.Activate

'Copy VolCap Graph
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("VolCap").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wkbAll.Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("VolCap").Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
wkbTemp.Activate

'Copy CapRet Graph
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CapRet").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wkbAll.Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CapRet").Activate
ActiveChart.Paste
wkbTemp.Activate

'Copy DisTime Graph
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("DisTime").Activate
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
wkbAll.Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("DisTime").Activate
ActiveChart.Paste

DoEvents

wkbTemp.Close (False)

DoEvents

  x = x + 1

Wend

DoEvents

'Save the merged File
wkbAllname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("merged", fileFilter:="microsoft 
excel files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
If wkbAllname <> False Then
MsgBox "File Saved as " & wkbAllname
Else: End
End If

DoEvents

wkbAll.SaveAs wkbAllname

DoEvents

End Sub
```

Comment: So it fails on this line `wkbTemp.Close (False)` ?

Comment: Yes - but if I skip this line, it will also fail on the wkball.SaveAs

Comment: You can also try `.Checkin` since they are SharePoint Files, then call `.Close` after they are checked in, shouldn't be the reason why its crashing tho

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kubie. Unfortunately neither approach seems to help - still crashes when attempting to close the file. I should also mention that the same thing happens when working with local files!

Comment: Ah! I have looked at the crash log, and  "chart.dll" was flagged - could be something wrong with my chart merging operation... any ideas?

Comment: From event viewer:
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\chart.dll